# Why does my windows service stops after computer is restarted?

Tags: c#, windows, service

I made a windows service using C# which serves as an interface between AB PLC and a Laser device. All it does is it takes barcode number from the PLC and sends to the Laser device for laser marking.

The two main function that I used are StartEvent() and StopEvent() for the service. I don't have any issue in my code. The issue that I have is after I power cycle the computer the service stops. And, I have to manually restart the service.

How can I resolve this power loss recovery issue? Am I missing some code in my service for shutdown event?
Please note, I have used third party libraries for PLC and laser. And, communication setting for both of these PLC and laser are stored on SQL database, and I have use ado.net for that...

I have attached the configuration of service below.

[image]
I have Recovery settings as below but this didn't help

[image]

And default computer registry for current control set as below
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting it to Automatic (Delayed Start)? Sometimes that works because your service may have a dependency that needs to be running first. It's worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I did that too..but didn't work.

Comment: Did you check windows event viewer?

Comment: no I haven't looked on it. I thought I had to change some key on current control set registry however, I screwed and got my whole computer broken. It doesn't start when I log in. I think I blew up OS. So, I am tryna get experts help here..

Comment: @RandRandom I just looked on the Eventviewer and found two errors which depends on one of the service I am using for Laser device.

Comment: Sounds to me like you found your issue or do you still need help?

Comment: Yup, that's right, I found my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved this problem. The issue was nothing but "Race Condition".

My app is dependent on an SQL server. So, I had two choices to fix it. I added SQL server dependency by writing some commands in the command prompt. (You can google those commands to add service dependency).
The next thing, I tried and which in my view is solid than the first option is to add a delay in the service during start-up. This has to be done in your code. In my case, I did service using C#, so I added synchronous thread delay in the app.